# sed : have a range finishing with the last occurrence of a pattern (greedy range)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, ed

Take the following file :

```
$ cat f1
stu vwx yza
uvw xyz abc
abc def ghi
def ghi jkl
ghi jkl mno
jkl mno pqr
mno pqr stu
pqr stu vwx
stu vwx yza
```

To print all lines from the first one containing `abc` to **the first one** containing `mno` with GNU `sed` :

```
$ sed -n '/abc/,/mno/p' f1
uvw xyz abc
abc def ghi
def ghi jkl
ghi jkl mno
```

How could I print all lines until **the last one** containing `mno`, e.g. how could I get the following result :

```
uvw xyz abc
abc def ghi
def ghi jkl
ghi jkl mno
jkl mno pqr
mno pqr stu
```

In other words, is there a way to make GNU `sed`'s range selection greedy ?

**Update**

In my setting :

- If `mno` is missing, it should print out everything until the end of the file.
- `mno` cannot occur before the first `abc`.
- There's always at least one `abc`, and `abc` and `mno` are never on the same line

**EDIT**
I just added a dummy `stu vwx yza` line at the start, so that the file doesn't start with a line including `abc` (to avoid solutions that start from the first line - they should start from the first line having `abc` in it)

Comment: One problem here is that this might require holding an arbitrary number of lines in memory, however it might be implemented.

Comment: is the input **always** going to be in a file or could it come from a pipe? If it's not always stored in a file then that would rule out several of the solutions posted so far.

Comment: @EdMorton : in my case the input is always a file

Comment: @αғsнιη : In my specific case there's always at least one `abc`, and `abc` and `mno` are never on the same line. Only `mno` can be missing. I'm not looking for a solution that can handle all theoretic cases. So far I have 3 awk, 2 sed and 1 perl solutions that are all perfectly working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/abc/,$!d;0,/mno/b;:1;/mno/b;$d;N;b1' file
```

Work algorithm:
Two address ranges are used.
The first `/abc/,$!d;` removes everything up to the first pattern match.
The second `0,/mno/b;` up to a match with the pattern `/mno/`, sends each line buffer(pattern space) to the output bypassing the remaining script, thereby preventing the deletion if the pattern is not found in the file.
The rest of the script `:1;/mno/b;$d;N;b1` works in a loop. In the editor buffer, lines are appended until a pattern match occurs. If a `/mno/` pattern is encountered, the entire buffer is sent to the output, bypassing the rest of the script. If no match occurs, the buffer is deleted at the last line.

Comment: A lot of nice solutions have been given (`awk`, `Perl`, `sed` and `ex`). I mark this one as accepted because (a) my question was about `sed`, and (b) it's nice and short (there's also Philippos' `sed` solution below, but it's a little longer). Quasimodo's `ex` solution is nice and short too (`printf '%s\n' '1?mno?' ke $/abc/ ks "'s,'ep" | ex file`). `awk` and `perl` solutions seem to be significantly longer than `sed` or `ed`

Comment: Of course, the shorter they are the more arcane (less readable) they are. (And I say this as someone who regularly uses sed and, occasionally, ex.) It's all about trade-offs. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use `awk` if it is an option. You could mark the lines for pattern start and pattern stop and print those lines in one-pass of the file (involves storing lines starting from the first line containing `abc` till the last line in a buffer)

```
awk '/abc/ && !start {
  start = NR
}
/mno/ {
  stop = NR
}
start { line[NR] = $0 }
END {
  if ( !stop ) {
    stop = NR
  }
  for ( s = start; s <= stop; s++ )
    print line[s]
}' file
```

Note that this will not work, when the start pattern is not present, printing only a series of blank lines.

Answer (score 4):

Another `awk` solution with less buffering:

```
awk '!f&&/abc/{f=1} f==1; f==2{buf=buf $0 ORS} f&&/mno/{f=2; printf "%s",buf; buf=""}' input.txt
```

- This will print everything starting with the first occurence of `abc` (where it sets a flag `f` to 1) up to and including the first occurence of `mno`. The `f==1` statement outside of the rule blocks instructs `awk` to print the current line as long as `f` is set to `1`.
- Then, the content of all lines after each occurence of `mno` (where `f` now has the value 2) is stored in a buffer `buf`, which is printed and cleared at the next occurence of `mno`. To ensure we correctly cope with situations where the first `mno` occurs *before* the first `abc`, we demand that `f` be set at least to 1 before applying that logic.

It will therefore store at most the text between two occurences occurence of `mno`, or the last occurence of `mno` and end-of-file (only that the latter part will never be printed).

If you want to exchange speed with memory efficiency, the following two-pass method won't rely on buffering at all:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if (/abc/&&!start) {start=FNR} else if (/mno/) {end=FNR}; next} FNR>=start&&(!end||FNR<=end)' input.txt input.txt
```

This will process the file twice (hence it is specified twice as argument).

- The first time, when `FNR`, the per-file line-counter is equal to `NR`, the global line counter, we look for the first occurence of `abc` and the last occurence of `mno`, and store their line numbers in `start` and `end`, respectively.
- In the second pass, we print lines as long as the `FNR` counter is between (and including) `start` end `end` (or simply if it is greater/equal than `start` if `end` is unset).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think sed can be made greedy, no. A possible workaround, simple but inefficient, would be to process the file twice. Once to get the line range and another to print. For instance:

```
$ perl -lne '$s||=$. if /abc/; $e=$. if /mno/; }{ print "$s $e"' file | 
    while read start end; do sed -n "$start,${end}p" file; done
abc def ghi
def ghi jkl
ghi jkl mno
jkl mno pqr
mno pqr stu
```

Alternatively, if you want to handle cases where either one or both patterns are missing:

```
perl -lne '$s||=$. if /abc/; $e=$. if /mno/; }{ $s||=1; $e||=$.; print "$s $e"' file | 
    while read start end; do sed -n "$start,${end}p" file; done
```

If `abc` isn't found, it will print from the beginning of the file. If `mnc` is not found, it will print from `abc` (or the beginning, if `abc` isn't there) until the end. If neither pattern is found it will, of course, print nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Collect lines until a `mno` sequence makes them ready to print:

```
sed -e '/abc/,$!d;:loop' -e'/mno/{p;d;}' -e '$d;N;bloop'
```

- `/abc/,$!d` `d`eletes everything except for the range from first `abc` line to the end. This also handles the case when there is no `abc` at all.
- Then we need to `:loop`.
- `/mno/{p;d;}` if there is `mno` in the pattern space, `p`rint and start over.
- `$d` if we reach the last line without `mno`, `d`elete everything in the buffer. Unfortunately, this means no output, if there is no `mno` at all.
- Otherwise append the `N`ext line and continue the loop.

Comment: @ikkachu : exact, I didn't see that one. Yes, you are right, this answer doesn't exactly give me what I'm looking for. I tested all solutions, so far the only one that handles that case is terdon's Perl one. But it doesn't handle the case where `mno` is missing (see AdminBee's comment above)

Comment: Doesn"t handle the case where `mno` is missing

Answer (score 2):

You can collect all lines, starting from the `abc` line in hold space and then use the greedy nature of `.*` to delete everything after the last `mno`:

```
sed '/abc/,$!d;H;$!d;x;s/\n//;s/\(.*mno[^\n]*\).*/\1/'
```

- `/abc/,$!d` is to `d`elete everything before the first `abc` line (or the whole file, if there is no `abc` line at all)
- `H;$!d` is the classical pattern to collect the whole file in the hold space (note that this can be a problem for very big files)
- we `x`change buffers instead of using `g` to avoid copying a large buffer
- `s/\n//` removes the wrong newline at the beginning, produced by appending to the empty hold space
- `s/\(.*mno[^\n]*\n\).*/\1/` removes everything after the *last* `mno` line (or prints the whole remaining file, if there is no `mno` line, as requested). Note that `[^\n]` is not POSIX and will work only on some versions like GNU `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '(S:g/ <( ^ .*? $$ \n )> ^^ .*? abc .*? $$ // andthen S:g/ ^^ .* mno .*? $$  <( .*? $)> //).put for lines.join("\n");'
```

Sample Input:

```
1. stu vwx yza
2. uvw xyz abc
3. abc def ghi
4. def ghi jkl
5. ghi jkl mno
6. jkl mno pqr
7. mno pqr stu
8. pqr stu vwx
9. stu vwx yza
10. mno pqr stu
11. xyz xyz xyz
```

Sample Output:

```
2. uvw xyz abc
3. abc def ghi
4. def ghi jkl
5. ghi jkl mno
6. jkl mno pqr
7. mno pqr stu
8. pqr stu vwx
9. stu vwx yza
10. mno pqr stu
```

Note above that Sample Output is a return of lines 2-through-10 when fed the 11 line Sample Input. Also, when the Sample Input is truncated to only lines 1-through-10 (i.e. with `mno` on the last line), the Raku code above still (correctly) returns lines 2-through-10.

Thanks to @ImHere and @ChennyStar for prodding me in the comments to come up with a more robust Raku solution.

https://raku.org

Comment: Nope, add the line `aaa abc bbb` at the end of your example and see what it does.

Comment: It seems quite surprising that this solution doesn't print lines 8 and 9 and then prints line 10. That is not **one** (or a) range. The OP question did ask for a range from the first `abc` found to the last `mno` found. So, technically, an `abc` after the last `mno` should not be printed. YMMV

Comment: Answers that work with only **one** input are not that much useful. Given that you are set in showing that `raku` is very capable. And given that `raku` is a high level language, a solution that works for simple conditions should be possible.

Comment: I just noticed that this solution doesn't work if the last line contains `mno`, which clearly hasn't be excluded by the OP's (me!) use case. So this solution doesn't cover my use case.

Comment: @ImHere edited above.

Comment: @ChennyStar edited above.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed`
Note: first abc line does not have mno as per OP so we can exploit that fact in the Below sed code.

```
sed -e '
  /abc/,$!d
  /mno/{h;b;}
  $!{N;s/^/\n/;D;}
  x;/./d;x
' file
```

---

In this method we use the slurp mode `-z` to read in the full file in the pattern space.
Then we delete till before the first line containing abc. After that reach the last mno line using the greediness of regex.

```
sed -Ez '
  s/abc/\x0&/
  s/.*\n(.*)\x0/\1/
  s/(.*mno[^\n]*\n).*/\1/
' file
```

---

Yet another way is a two-pass approach
where we record the line numbers of the
first abc line and the last mno line. In
case no mno present we fill in $ in it's place.
Then using these two numbers we
construct a sed command
begin,end`p`;end`q`

```
sed -n '/abc/{=;:a;n;/mno/=;ba}' file |
sed -En '
  1{h;$s/.*/$/;}
  ${x;G;}
  s/\n(.*)/,\1p&q/p
' | sed -nf - file
```

---

We can use `perl` to slurp the file and then  the whole file is one long string which we
burn from both ends and stop when
our conditions are met.

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s/^.*\n// until /^.*abc/;    /mno/||next;
  s/.*\n$// until /mno.*$/;
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are more ways using the sed editor
to get the desired output.

```
sed -n '
  /\n/{/mno/!d;P;D;}
  /abc/,$H;$!d
  z;x;G;/mno/D
  s/.//;s/.$//p
' file
```

- Save the file from the first /abc/ till eof in the hold space.
- print the top of pattern space while we still can see /mno/ anywhere in it.
- Then clip the top of pattern space and repeat previous step.
- Stop when /mno/ is no longer visible.
- Alternative ly, before beginning this P;D cycle if there is no /mno/ then just print the whole of hold space.

---

Another method where we store lines in hold only until /mno/ is seen. At which point we flip and print what was in hold.

```
sed -n '
  /abc/,$!d
  /mno/!{H;ba;}
  x;p;:a
  ${x;//P;//!p}
' file | sed 1d
```

---

Here is the Python way using the versatile itertools module groupby method to get the job done.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
ifile,start,stop = sys.argv[1:]
G,K,F = [],[],lambda x: x.find(stop)
with open(ifile) as f:
  for _ in f:
    if not _.find(start): continue
    for t in it.groupby(f,F):
      G.append(list(t[1]))
      K += [t[0] > -1]
if len(K) > 1 and not K[-1]: G.pop()
print(*[e for L in G for e in L], sep="",end="")
' file "abc" "mno"
```